How does TS template literal inference work with multiple interpolations?
Trying the following code:
type Test1<T extends string> = T extends `${infer P}${number}` ? P : never
type Test2<T extends string> = T extends `${infer P}.${number}` ? P : never

type T1 = Test1<'Test1'>
type T2 = Test2<'Test.2'>

T1 is inferred as never, while T2 is correctly inferred as Test. It seems that TS simply stops parsing P after one character, and fails since the rest of the string does not match number. I couldn't find a documentation for using infer in template literals, is it a bug/limitation in TS syntax? Is there any way to extract a prefix out of a string such Foo123?

You could use a recursive type:
Playground
type Test1<T extends string> = T extends `${number}` ? '' : T extends `${infer P}${infer B}` ? `${P}${Test1<B>}` : never; // add `${number}${string}` to match the first digit
type Test2<T extends string> = T extends `${infer P}.${number}` ? P : never;

type T1 = Test1<'Test1000'>
type T2 = Test2<'Test.2'>

